# Python Matplotlib LEGEND customise

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Is there a way to shift the lower two metrics to the left under the red line in the legend?
Either that or move the red line in the legend to the right side of 0.93?
Failing that is there a quick way to separate the R2 from RMSE and MAE and have two legends that don't interfere with each other- by this I mean I can stack one above the other and they have different settings- (I have tried and they don't do this)

This is my code for the legend part:

```
handles = [mpl_patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="white", ec="white",
                                 lw=0, alpha=0)] * 4
lines = []
handles[0] = Line2D([0], [0], color='red',lw=3)
labels = []
labels.append("R² = {0:.2g}".format(Rsquared))
#labels.append("MSE = {0:.2g}".format(mse))
leg = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='best', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7)

labels.append("RMSE = {0:.2g}".format(rmse))
labels.append("MAE = {0:.2g}".format(mae))
```

If there is even a way to label the red line itself on the graph that would be great aswell. This is the code for the graph itself:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y_test, y_predicted ,s=10,color='darkslateblue',linewidths=1)
ax.plot([y.min(), y.max()], [y.min(), y.max()], 'k-', lw=1.75)
ax.set_xlabel('Actual (%)',fontsize='large')
ax.set_ylabel('Predicted (%)',fontsize='large')
y_test, y_predicted = y_test.reshape(-1,1), y_predicted.reshape(-1,1)
ax.plot(y_test, LinearRegression().fit(y_test, y_predicted).predict(y_test), color="red", lw=1.75)
```

The black line is y=x.

PLEASE HELP! I have been at this for days. Its such a small change but vital for my report.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not completely able understand what you actually need or how to plot your exact data, I think you mean to simply separate your legends? Using your code, for example, here's a dummy plot with separate legends:

```
plt.figure()

handles = [
    Line2D([0], [0], color='red',lw=3),
    Line2D([0], [0], color='white',lw=3),
    Line2D([0], [0], color='white',lw=3)
]
    
labels = []
labels.append("R² = {0:.2g}".format(0.93))
L1 = plt.legend(handles[:1], labels, loc='upper left', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7)
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(L1)
labels_ = []
labels_.append("RMSE = {0:.2g}".format(0.033))
labels_.append("MAE = {0:.2g}".format(0.023))

plt.legend(handles[1:], labels_, loc='lower right', fontsize='x-large',
          fancybox=True, framealpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

This would give something like:

[image: legends]

Please take a look at matplotlib's documentation for [Multiple legends on the same Axes](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes) as well if you need.